# Magento2 PWA images missing - development environment

Tags: magento2, product-images, pwa, category-image

I have followed below URL.

> https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

Setup is successfully installed and my local environment is connected to PWA application, but all of my images went missing while browsing PWA. as it is taking images url something like below

> https://my-pwa.com:8477/media/catalog/category/timeless.jpg

Any Configuration for changing this or any workaround.

Comment: Can you please share your virtual host file?

Comment: I haven't created any, I have just changed the .env file for the custom domain.

Comment: Go to `packages/venia-concept/.env` and add **pub** 

    MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_PRODUCT=" /pub/media/catalog/product"
    MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_CATEGORY=" /pub/media/catalog/category"

Comment: Thanks, it helps me, i have also added project name before /pub

Answer (score 4):

Go to `packages/venia-concept/.env` and add **pub** directory, if still not works you can add whole project URL.

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_PRODUCT="/pub/media/catalog/product"
MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_CATEGORY="/pub/media/catalog/category"
```

Comment: I am just wondering that what it should be done when we move to production.

Comment: in my setup it's working without change in env file.

Comment: what you have put there?